# Dropping Winforms components onto WPF window

Tags: wpf, winforms, components, toolbox

I currently have some non-visual components that were written in Winforms. I added them to the toolbox, and can drag/drop them from the toolbox onto the form and it creates objects of that component to use. I was wondering if there was a way to drag/drop these Winforms created components onto a WPF app the same way? As of right now, the component is grayed out in the toolbox, and I have to manually add a reference to the .dll of the component. I then have to initialize the object in the code-behind manually.

Again, this is for a non-visual component. The reason I'm asking is because this is for a person that originally worked with Delphi and wants to be able to drag/drop components like that.

Comment: No.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That's just for visual components though right? Haven't tested with visual ones but I have tried using a reference to `WindowsFormsIntegration` as well as doing `xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"` in the XAML.